# Clear slicer cache only if slicer is filtered

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel VBA macro to set slicers to certain values as determined by the user. However, before doing this, I want to clear any previous selections. Currently I just use:

```
For Each cache In ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches
 cache.ClearManualFilter
Next cache
```

But this is extremely slow, so I would like only to clear the filter if the slicer actually is filtered. So far I have:

```
Dim cache As SlicerCache
Dim RefreshNeeded As Boolean
RefreshNeeded = False

For Each cache In ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches
    For i = 1 To cache.SlicerCacheLevels.Count
        If cache.SlicerCacheLevels(i).SlicerItems.Count <> cache.SlicerCacheLevels(i).VisibleSlicerItems.Count Then
            RefreshNeeded = True
        End If
    Next i
        If RefreshNeeded = True Then
            cache.ClearManualFilter
        End If
    RefreshNeeded = False
Next cache
```

This results in a run-time error.

By temporarily replacing `cache.SlicerCacheLevels(i).VisibleSlicerItems.Count` with a number, I found that this is the problem. [Microsoft support](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.slicercache.visiblesliceritems.aspx) states that the `.VisibleSlicerItems` property isn't available when working with a Cube, which I am.

Is there a way around this, or another technique for identifying only the slicers that are filtered?

Comment: I am in the same situation. Excel wants to clear the 50+ caches in my table, yet I only have 5 slicers being used. It takes two minutes to clear the selections!